In Azure B2C Technical profile, how to rollback user creation on REST API error
As a last step of the self asserted technical profile, a REST API call is being made as shown below. The REST API associate a B2C Object id to user profile in database. If there is an error, I would like to rollback the user write performed in previous validation technical profile (AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail)? Is there a way to achieve this compensation transaction on REST API failure?
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

        <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST - SingupComplete" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>

Any help is highly appreciated.
I tried the following with no luck?

In REST API, catch the error and delete the B2C account using objectId - Getting user not found error by Graph library. Looks like B2C has not persisted the claims into B2C store. May be it does after the user journey completes.
ContinueOnError on the REST API Validation profile and create another technical profile to check for the error record and invoke AAD-UserDeleteUsingObjectId. Having issues with raising error back to user.


Another option could be to create the user in your REST API instead of in the policy.

Just be aware if you do that that there could be a replication delay and the user record may not be immediately available to B2C (via its Graph technical profiles) when your API returns.

@juunas Thank you. This requires passing all claims (including password/new password/security questions) to the REST API, which is not acceptable.

@DaveD Agree. I've encountered a similar delay issue in the opposite direction when attempting to read the user record in the REST API, which was created in the technical profile just before the call.
